# Matplotlib Crash When Figure 1 not Closed Last

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am plotting mutliple figures using Matplotlib using Python 3.4.

When the multiple figures are open and I close the windows closing the first figure last (ie once all other figures are closed) python does not crash.

If, however, I close the first figure that was plotted first and then close the rest Python crashes.

It seems as though you need to close the windows in such an order that the first window that was opened must be closed last. Has anyone else experienced and is there a solution?

Here is a trivial example code that can be used to verify:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1) # the first figure
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.figure(2) # a second figure
plt.plot([4,5,6]) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have managed to solve this issue has been to use Qt4 as the matplotlib backend.

Simply add the following two lines of code after importing matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['backend'] = "qt4agg"
mpl.rcParams['backend.qt4'] = "PySide"
```

This is what I do on Python 3 and have no plot closing errors

Comment: Great! Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

As discussed [on the IPython bug tracker](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8921#issuecomment-151046708) this is a bug in a TCL/TK library which is shipped with python 3.4 on windows.

Changing the backend to Qt works around the problem by using a different gui framework.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to do effectively what should be done by `plt.close('all')`:

```
def closeall(): # this closes all figures in reverse order
    l = plt.get_fignums()
    l.reverse()
    for a in l:
        plt.close(a)
```

Answer (score -2):

Whenever you are plotting multiple figures, do not use `plt.show`, create your figures separately in a `figure` instance and add an `Axes` using `add_subplot`. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(211) # the first subplot in the first figure
ax1.plot([1,2,3])
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(212) # the second subplot in the first figure
ax2.plot([4,5,6])
plt.suptitle('Easy as 1,2,3')
fig1.show()

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax3 = fig2.add_subplot(211) # the first subplot in the second figure
ax3.plot([4,5,6]) 
ax4 = fig2.add_subplot(212) # the second subplot in the second figure
ax4.plot([4,5,6])
plt.suptitle('Easy as 1,2,3')
fig2.show()
```

By doing so you can still use your python shell even when the plots are active. This is the best way to plot multiple plots.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This did not work. I need to use separate figure windows for reporting purposes and the problem of python crashing if figure 1 is not closed last still exists.

Comment: @RicDavimes: By using the above method I have mentioned, you still have separate figure windows, which is the proper way to go about. But if the problem still persists then it has to do with `matplotlib` in Python 3.4